# Can I make a function that does not return until media is finished playing?

Tags: java, video, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I need a function that plays a video for me and returns when the video has ended, NOT BEFORE. So when I write "play('video1'); play('video2');" both videos must be played back to back. I have made several attempts to do this but all attempts so far either don't play the video's at all or play all video's at the same time. Below I have posted a basic function to play a video, now I just need a way to delay the return. Any idea's?

```
private static void play(String name) throws InterruptedException {
    Media media = new Media(uri(name));
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.setAutoPlay(true);
    view.setMediaPlayer(player);
}
```

I tried the following:

```
player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> { return; });
```

in combination with an infinite loop at the end of the function. That for some reason prevents the video from playing. Any better idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX, like all UI toolkits, is *event driven*. This means you write code that responds to events, rather than write one big loop that does everything you want. (Assuming you are starting the media player from the FX Application Thread, if your method did not exit until the media finished, then the UI would not be able to update, or respond to any user events, until the media finished, which is not what you want to happen.)

So you need to use an `onEndOfMedia` handler to play the next media, if there is another one to play:

```
private String[] videos = {"video1", "video2"};
private int currentVideoIndex = 0 ;

private void playNextVideo() {
    Media media = new Media(uri(videos[currentVideoIndex]));
    currentVideoIndex++ ;
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
        if (currentVideoIndex < videos.length) {
            playNextVideo();
        }
    });
    player.setAutoPlay(true);
    view.setMediaPlayer(player);
}
```

Comment: Hello James, thank you for your quick response, the notion that javafx is event driven really helped. I am using your function and it's working great. I am wondering whether there is a nice way to prevent the short white flicker inbetween two video's. (Since all my video's start and end roughly on the same screen i was thinking about setting a frame from the video as the background of the scene. Is there a better way to achieve this effect?)

Comment: @Joan Not sure: I would have to experiment with that and don't have suitable video files to hand. I suspect the "flicker" is during the short time while the media is still being read from disk (or wherever) but after the call to `view.setMediaPlayer(...)` has completed. You might be able to do something akin to "queuing up the next video ahead of time", perhaps by loading creating the next `Media` object (or even `MediaPlayer` object) one video ahead. The code might get complex for that, though.